# SQL Delete specific rows based on date and criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete, drop-duplicates

I've got a table that has duplicate data that needs to be cleaned up. Consider the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE #StackOverFlow
(
    [ctrc_num] int, 
    [Ctrc_name] varchar(6),
    [docu] bit, 
    [adj] bit, 
    new bit, 
    [some_date] datetime
);
    
INSERT INTO #StackOverFlow
    ([ctrc_num], [Ctrc_name], [docu], [adj], [new], [some_date])
VALUES
    (12345, 'John R', null, null, 1, '2023-12-11 09:05:13.003'),
    (12345, 'John R', 1, null, 0, '2023-12-11 09:05:12.987'),
    (12345, 'John R', null, null, 1, '2023-12-11 09:05:12.947'),
    (56789, 'Sam S', null, null, 1, '2023-12-11 09:05:13.003'),
    (56789, 'Sam S', null, null, 1, '2023-12-11 09:05:12.987'),
    (56789, 'Sam S', 1, null, 0, '2023-12-11 09:05:12.947'),
    (78945, 'Pat P', null, null, 1, '2023-12-11 09:05:13.003'),
    (78945, 'Pat P', null, null, 1, '2023-12-11 09:05:12.987'),
    (78945, 'Pat P', null, null, 1, '2023-12-11 09:05:12.947');
```

This gives me:

```
[ctrc_num]  [Ctrc_name] [docu]  [adj]   [new]   [some_date]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
12345        John R     NULL    NULL    1       2023-12-11 09:05:13.003
12345        John R     1       NULL    0       2023-12-11 09:05:12.987
12345        John R     NULL    NULL    1       2023-12-11 09:05:12.947
56789        Sam S      NULL    NULL    1       2023-12-11 09:05:13.003
56789        Sam S      NULL    NULL    1       2023-12-11 09:05:12.987
56789        Sam S      1       NULL    0       2023-12-11 09:05:12.947
78945        Pat P      NULL    NULL    1       2023-12-11 09:05:13.003
78945        Pat P      NULL    NULL    1       2023-12-11 09:05:12.987
78945        Pat P      NULL    NULL    1       2023-12-11 09:05:12.947
```

What I need to do is delete from the table duplicates. If new is 0, delete the records where new is 1. If all records have new = 1 keep the newest record and delete the older ones.

The result should look like this:

```
[ctrc_num]  [Ctrc_name] [docu]  [adj]  [new]    [some_date]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
12345        John R     1       NULL    0       2023-12-11 09:05:12.987
56789        Sam S      1       NULL    0       2023-12-11 09:05:12.947
78945        Pat P      NULL    NULL    1       2023-12-11 09:05:13.003
```

I've tried ROW_NUMBER:

```
;WITH RankedByDate AS
(
    SELECT 
        ctrc_num, Ctrc_name,
        docu, adj, new, some_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Ctrc_num, Ctrc_name, [docu],[adj], [new] 
                           ORDER BY some_date DESC) AS rNum
    FROM 
        #StackOverFlow
)
SELECT * 
FROM RankedByDate
```

This separates the ones with new = 0, but I still have the ones with new = 1 that are ordered.

Grouping gives me the records that are duplicated but no way to delete the ones needed to be deleted:

```
SELECT [ctrc_num]
    ,[Ctrc_name]
    ,[docu]
    ,[adj]
    ,[new]
FROM 
    #StackOverFlow
GROUP BY 
    [ctrc_num]
    ,[Ctrc_name]
    ,[docu]
    ,[adj]
    ,[new]
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: What constitutes a duplicate?  Same `[ctrc_num] ` **and**  `[Ctrc_name]`?

Comment: Post the query you've tried, even if not working.

Comment: There are no duplicate rows since no two rows are equal. Therefore you must specify what you mean by duplicate. Also, which value of the rows not building the duplicate do you want to keep?

Comment: Unless there can be more than one new = 0, your logic can be summarized as remove all rows partitioned by ctrc_num order by new, some_date desc where row_number > 1. It shouldn't be very hard to come up with sql corresponding to the above.

Comment: Duplicates are the same ```[ctrc_num``` and ```[Ctrc_name]```

Comment: Would there ever be a case where all rows for a given `ctrc_num` have `new = 0`? If so, would you still prefer to delete all but one - keeping the one with the latest `some_date`? If so, the above logic holds. If not, you will need to add extra filter criteria.

Comment: *(corrected repost)* Check out the "how to delete" link above. As for the specific ordering of row number, think about what you want to keep - `new = 0` is preferred over `new = 1`, and among those, you prefer the latest date. Next define the `OVER()` qualifier to match. In your case, I believe you want `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ctrc_num ORDER BY new, some_date DESC) AS RowNum`. The preferred (possibly only) row will than have `RowNum = 1`, so you want to delete everything else `RowNum >= 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break the problem down into it's parts

1. "If new is 0, delete the records where new is 1"

   ```sql
   delete from #StackOverFlow
   where [new] = 1
   and [ctrc_num] in (select [ctrc_num]
                      from #StackOverFlow
                      where [new] = 0);
   ```
2. "If all records have new = 1 keep the newest record and delete the older ones"
   Use a CTE to add a row number based on the date and partitioned by the [ctrc_num] such that the "first" record in each group is the one you want to keep - if there is only 1 row in a group that's the one you want to keep anyway. Then delete everything else

   ```sql
   ;with cte as
   (
       select 
            [ctrc_num]  
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ctrc_num] ORDER BY [ctrc_num], [some_date] DESC) as rw
       from #StackOverFlow
   )
   DELETE FROM cte where rw <> 1;
   ```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I was hoping I would be able to eliminate the duplicate without having to break it into more than one part, but this works.

Comment: you can write this as subquery too, no need for CTE.

Comment: @TN - Why? In step 1 I deleted any records where new = 1  if there was a subsequent new = 0. So either there is only a single record per [ctrc_num] and new = 1 OR there is/are 1+ records for a [ctrc_num] where new = 0. Sorting by `new` only becomes relevant if trying to do both steps at once.

Comment: @kool_kris - as you will see from siggemannen's solution, it is possible to do what you want in a single query.  But when you are trying to figure out how to do something it is good practice to break it down first.  See also "SQL Antipatterns" by Bill Karwin - Chapter 18 "Spaghetti Query" - "Solve a Complex Problem in One Step".
You can always merge the "bits" together afterwards - once you have something working. Personally, I'd rather have three simple queries I can follow than one complex one that has me puzzled :-)

Comment: @CHill60 I stand corrected. I was thinking in terms of a single statement solution, like what Alex Kudryashev posted. (Earlier comment has been deleted.)

Comment: @TN - Phew. I did scratch my head for a while though - at least you made me think :-)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do what you want is a single query.

```
;with cte as(
    select [ctrc_num], [Ctrc_name], [docu],[adj], [new], [some_date]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [ctrc_num] -- group by [ctrc_num]
        order by [new], --0 then 1
        [some_date] desc --newest first
        ) rn
    from #StackOverFlow
)
delete cte
where rn>1
;

select * from #StackOverFlow
```